# Getting the error "ApiKey invalid" for hotel live prices

Tags: skyscanner

I'm trying to get the a list of current hotel prices but I can't get my API Key to work. I've had it for a couple days so I know it isn't too new. I even tried the example in the docs (after fixing the dates):

http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v2/UK/EUR/en-GB/27539733/2016-12-04/2016-12-10/2/1?apiKey=myKey

While it worked for the demo key it wouldn't work for mine. I also tried it on the ec2 micro I'm using for testing with Python and get a response with u'{"errors":["ApiKey invalid"]}':

```
SKY_SCAN_URL = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v2/"
sky_key = get_sky_scan_key()
def get_hotels(request):
        entityid = request.GET['entityid']
        checkindate = date_formatter(request.GET['start'])
        checkoutdate = date_formatter(request.GET['end'])
        rooms = request.GET['rooms']
        guests = request.GET['guests']
        FINAL_SKY_URL = "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/?apiKey=%s" % (
            SKY_SCAN_URL, 'US', 'USD', 'en-US', entityid, checkindate, checkoutdate, guests, rooms, sky_key)

        sky_response = requests.get(FINAL_SKY_URL)
```

This function outputs a get request with a URL like this:
http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v2//US/USD/en-US/20.7983626,-156.3319253-latlong/2016-09-07/2016-09-14/1/1/?apiKey=myKey

Any advice on what the possible issue could be would be awesome, thanks!

Edit:
To be more specific I'm looking for reasons why my API Key is invalid. I'm not familiar with skyscan and while I've added an app from the skyscanner dashboard by clicking the travel api and copied the key into my project and directly into a valid url my key is showing as bad. Are there any additional steps or things that I need to take into account?

Comment: Try printing the complete URL out before requesting. check if that works in opened directly on a browser.

Comment: @majidarif I already did but no luck with that either. I went ahead and added it within the question just now for anyone who may notice if there is an issue with the way it's formatted.

Comment: Their documentation is a bit misleading, they talk about `Query string` but its actually url params. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about how you're creating the URL but it seems like it shouldn't be built that way. (most likely due to their misleading documentation)

This:

```
http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v3/?apiKey=myKey&checkoutdate=2016-09-14&checkindate=2016-09-07&currency=USD&rooms=1&entityid=20.7983626%2C-156.3319253-latlong&local=en-US&market=US&guests=1
```

Should be:

```
http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v3/US/USD/en-US/20.7983626,-156.3319253-latlong/2016-09-07/2016-09-14/1/1/?apiKey=myKey
```

Your code should be something like:

```
SKY_SCAN_URL = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v3/"
FINAL_URL = "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/?apiKey=%s" % (SKY_SCAN_URL, market, currency, locale, entityid, checkindate, checkoutdate, guests, rooms, apiKey)

sky_response = requests.get(FINAL_URL)
```

I also suggest you do some tests [here](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/HotelsLivePricingQuickStart).

Comment: Thanks, I just plugged that in! That did solve half my problem and while it works for the demo key I'm still getting an invalid API Key error.

Comment: Then maybe you're using an invalid api key. Double check.

Comment: Did you request an API key? You can request one from: http://en.business.skyscanner.net/en-gb/contact

Comment: I did get it from them, I even made a 2nd just to be sure there wasn't some odd issue.

Comment: Then I can't help you any further as only you know your API key. My only advice is to double check your api key if it looks valid (similar with the demo key). Or maybe the problem lies on `get_sky_scan_key()`

Comment: Oh well, here's to hoping they check their E-Mail or stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

From their help site as of 17 days ago - 
https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us/articles/209452689-Why-is-my-API-key-returning-no-results-for-hotels-

"Our Hotels API is currently being reworked, and access is not available at present. Apologies for any inconvenience, when the new API is ready for use we will update the Skyscanner for Business site, so please check back there for updates."

Unclear when this changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since April 2017, skyScanner started re-working their Hotels API, thus stopping all ongoing API calls to LIVE Pricing APIs:
https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us/articles/209452689-Why-is-my-API-key-returning-no-results-for-hotels-
Hotels and Flights Cached Pricing and Browse services still working, though I am not sure if it is enough for your business case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Skyscanner has updated their Hotels API recently and the documentation can be found here: https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#hotels-live-prices